# How to cut an 'cilindrical' Object out of an Cuboid (sheet of wood)

Tags: modeling

I want to make a magazine holder in blender and I try to cut an 'cylindrical' Object out of an Cuboid (sheet of wood). I later want to cnc it so its best to have good geometry. The picture explains best. How would I achieve something like this? It's important to change measures later on and have perfect round corners still.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try boolean modifier?

Comment: Yes I tried! Unfortunately the geometry was not really nice. Is there a way to technically draw this?

Comment: The boolean modifier should be fine for that. Post an image of the problems you were getting when you used it. - You could even use it with an array modifier to cut out all the slots at once for your picture.

Answer (score 1):

Blender isn't really a CAD application, although there are some add-ons out there to make CAD-like work a little easier.

Just for fun, here's a kit to help make this object, mainly with modifiers, so it's easier to adjust.

[image]

- Starting with an L-shaped face to dimensions, preferably with no internal edges. The concave corner is given a vertex bevel-weight of 1.

Modifiers:

- *Bevel* (Vertex). By weight.  Shape: 0.5, Clamp Overlap, taken to maximum, so the clamp takes effect.
- *Mirror*

[image]

- *Array*, and *Decimate* (Planar), to get rid of excess internal edges
- *Solidify*, to thickness.

[image]

- Optional *Bevel* (Edge), by angle, to hold edges
- A little custom *Geometry Nodes* modifier to put the origin at the bottom left corner.

[image]

Comment: Wow this is really helpfull! Thanks for the clear explanation. I'll get to it! I am a cabinet maker and Blender is all I know, so I'll keep draw my furniture in Blender. A friend of mine also wrote a script to output all dimentions for sawing. If it works it works! Thanks!

Comment: @DaanVanHelsdingen Great!. You have to think  bit like a cabinetmaker to use Blender for hard-surface modelling.. make your own jigs.. take measurements and angles from existing parts.. etc. etc.